# How do I use hashset in actionscript

Tags: actionscript, data-structures, set, hashset

Right now I am using ArrayCollection. But I want to change that to Set as I want make sure do duplicate values come.

```
var addressList:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
```

One way is I can use Dictionary and store addresses as a key. And I can just use keys to iterate.
But I am looking for Java HashSet like implementation.

Comment: Why do you specifically need a hash set implementation?

Comment: Ok, fair enough (although any set would avoid duplicates.) Do you want a working class or hints on how to write one? ActionScripters for their most part are a very lazy bunch who don't bother with the notion of sets, and do it with arrays usually, hence apparent lack of implementations. People who use `haXe` however are a bit more serious, and like the other person has answered, polygonal.de have written an excellent compact class that pretty much clones Javas `HashSet` API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AS3 equivalent to HashMap or HashSet is the Dictionary class, and to a lesser extent, the Object class. Object keys are stored as strings, while with Dictionary the keys are objects. You can't have duplicate entries with either. Are you looking for a specific implementation other than that?

Comment: What will it look like ?

`var addressList:Object = new Object();`

How will I add keys ehere ?

Comment: You are confusing values with keys. Indeed, `Dictionary` can give you the functionality of a hash table, as is, but it won't give you the functionality of a set, not without some work on your part. This is because a `Dictionary` will allow duplicate values, while a set doesn't. Unless you use the keys in a `Dictionary` as values, of course.

Comment: ah, amn is right. Dictionary will prevent duplicate keys, not duplicate values, sorry. @priyank Once you've created your object/dictionary, it's as easy as saying `myObj["someKey"] = value;`. You can check if a key is there by using `if (myObj[keyToTest] == undefined) ...`. You iterate through it using a  `for( var key:* in myObj )` (for keys), or `for each( var value:* in myObj )` (for values)

Answer (score 2):

You want to [download](http://code.google.com/p/polygonal/downloads/detail?name=polygonal_ds_1.32.zip&can=2&q=) Polygonal Data Structures.  The swc contains a [HashSet](http://www.polygonal.de/doc/ds/types/de/polygonal/ds/HashSet.html).  If you want Java-style template syntax for Flash, you should also check out [Haxe](http://haxe.org/).